# Issues selecting all elements in SVG using D3 and Moment.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm using [Cal-Heatmap](http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/), [d3](http://d3js.org), and [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and I've got some data that is sorted out by month and year. The goal is to get it to select all of the "g" svg elements in the calendar when a specific month is selected. This is my code.

```
if (thisDate.classed("m_1 y_2013")){
    this.selectAll("g").class("higlight");
}
```

I've also tried replacing `this` with `d3` and `thisDate`, which is the variable of whatever month is clicked in the calendar. No matter which of the three I use I keep getting the error that those aren't functions. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what are `thisDate` and `this`?

Comment: `thisDate = d3.select(this);`. `this` is reffering to whatever month the user clicks on in the calheatmap visualization

Comment: but is `this` the DOM (SVG) element of that month?

Comment: No, the svg element of each month is `svg`. Is that what I should use instead?